# Install Windows Embedded Standard 7 from USB

Tags: installation, usb-flash-drive, windows-embedded-7

I would like to install Windows Embedded Standard 7 on a HP thin client. I downloaded the ISO file from the MSDN Subscription site but I'm struggling to make a bootable USB disk.

I tried using UltraISO's write disk function but it doesn't work.

Is there a simple way to make a bootable USB for Windows Embedded Standard 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is Microsoft's own tool called "Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool" for making bootable USB/DVD from ISO file. You can download it from [Microsoft Store](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool) or [CodePlex](http://wudt.codeplex.com/releases/view/37074).

P.S. Although it has 7 in name, it works on anything higher than Windows XP SP2.

Comment: I just used the Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool for creating a bootable USB with the Windows 7 installation files inside. Check this Ars Technica step by step guide to see how easy it is to create yours: http://arstechnica.com/business/news/2009/12/-the-usb-flash-drive.ars

Answer (score 1):

I see this kind of post throughout many forums. The tablets are 32 bit and DON't read the NTFS format either. It's as simple as that. The tool to make a bootable Windows X formats the key and makes it bootable yes but in NTFS. You need to copy all those files to a temp directory, reformat key in FAT32 then transfer them back. You will then be able to boot to the tablets and install whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can download this [tool](http://wintoflash.com/home/en/) to make USB bootable. And also check out [This link](http://wiki.toradex.com/index.php/USB_Boot_for_Windows_Embedded_Standard) to know about the windows embedded standard bootable USB. Hope it will worth for you not wasting of time. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Just updating this article as I had similar issues repairing a POS terminal for a client. Here's my solution:

- You can download the Windows Embedded POS Ready 7 software [from here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=26558) (I'm sure searching the same site will give you Win7 Embedded)
- Extract the rar files to create the ISO file
- Use Rufus to make it bootable (the default settings will need UEFI, set it to GPT/MBR if you need legacy boot).