# How can I boot Windows 7 embedded from USB 3.0?

Tags: windows-7, embedded, usb

I am trying to install and boot Windows 7 embedded via USB 3.0.

I am able to do this with USB 2.0 but not from USB 3.0. I have a Gigabyte GA-880GM-USB3L motherboard.

Is this possible? What do I need to do?

Comment: What happens when you try to boot to the USB 3.0 device?   Does it boot an fail?  Or does it not even boot at all?  I am sure I can boot Linux from a USB 3.0 device on different hardware.  Not sure why you wouldn't be able to boot something else, though Windows embedded might not have the actual drivers.  It could also be something with that hardware.

Comment: Related question -- http://superuser.com/questions/313450/install-windows-embedded-standard-7-from-usb

Comment: @minya will you please tell us what problem you are facing with usb 3.0?

Comment: @avirk, I'm seeing STOP 7B when booting WES7 from USB3.0, while USB2.0 boots fine. I'm not entirely sure this isn't a hardware problem, but seeing others have exactly the same (USB2, not USB3) makes me suspect Windows might be involved too.

Comment: I'd like to add (after seeing the two new answers below and yet again revisiting the links) that I am looking for information pertaining specifically to the Embedded edition of Windows 7 and (not so obvious from the question, but still implied) its USB Bootable Stack. With WES7, booting off USB is not a hack (like with regular 7), but a feature in its own right. For now, I'd like to keep it that way, hack-free, feature-based. So... Is this possible? What do I need to do?

Comment: You first need to respond to the answers that were posted.

Answer (score 1):

Almost anything is possible, however, Windows does not natively support USB 3.0 drivers, so it might get a bit complicated.

The following is adapted from one of [William Hilsum](https://superuser.com/users/4386/william-hilsum)'s posts.

This gets quite advanced, I hope you have a working knowledge of command prompt. I would recommend you add the various Microsoft directories to your path, or run the `Windows PE Tools Command Prompt` instead of the standard one. If I loose you at any point, please comment and I'll be happy to help.

What I recommend you do is download the [Microsoft Deployment Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=25175), and then  your USB drivers.

Once you've done that, load the `Deployment Workbench` and load the `WAIK` (Windows Automated Installation Kit).

Once this is downloaded, you can use the "copype" command to copy the required Windows PE files to a staging folder. Assuming you wanted `c:\win_pe_32` you would use:

```
copype.cmd x86 c:\win_pe_32
```

For 64 bit use:

```
copype.cmd x64 c:\win_pe_64
```

(I won't give two versions from now on, simply use common sense and replace 64 with 32!)

This will basically copy the required Windows PE files to the folder above.

Next, we need to mount the `boot.wim` file (The part that actually loads Windows PE). Do this with the ImageX command:

```
imagex /mountrw c:\win_pe_32\winpe.wim 1 c:\win_pe_32\mount
```

This will mount the `Wim` file to the `\mount` directory.

To load the driver, have the path to the `.inf` file and run:

```
peimg /inf=<path> c:\win_pe_32\mount\Windows
```

If you explore this folder, you can add additional files if you wish. Personally, I include ImageX so it is available from Windows PE.

Now commit the changes by typing:

```
imagex /unmount c:\win_pe_32\mount /commit
```

Now you simply overwrite the default `boot.wim` file with the `winpe.wim` you just changed.

```
copy c:\win_pe_32 c:\win_pe_32\iso\sources\boot.wim
```

Lastly, we use the Microsoft Mastering tool with the following command:

```
oscdimg -n -bc:\win_pe_32\etfsboot.com c:\win_pe_32\iso c:\win_pe_32\winpe_32.iso
```

Congratulations! You now have a new bootable Windows PE `iso` file with the drivers included.

You can burn this to disk, and hopefully, everything should work **as long as the driver is compatible with Windows PE**.

Comment: I'm using Image Configuration Editor (licensed from MS) for building WES7 images AND oscdimg. Because WES7 supports USB boot out of the box and has a specially designed USB stack for these purposes, I understand that the stack may not fully support USB3.0. I don't quite see how these instructions help or even provide a pointer to a possible solution. If you know of a Bootable USB stack replacement for USB3.0, that would be interesting. Next best thing, a USB3 driver to play nice with WES7's stack. Other than that, I just hope I'm missing something obvious. Like 3.0 not being supported at all.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer to a discussion that could be useful :
[[Tutorial] Boot Windows 7 from USB hard disk by karyonix](http://reboot.pro/9196/page__st__100).

This thread explores several subjects of interest and points to several other useful articles. I suggest reading it and its links and comparing them carefully to what you did.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to first install the OS on virtual PC following [these instructions](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LessVirtualMoreMachineWindows7AndTheMagicOfBootToVHD.aspx).
Also see this [blog](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2011/09/07/hp8540w-installing-windows-7-from-usb-key-usb3.aspx) where user has overcome to the problem by using the instruction of the above given article.

Answer (score 0):

Windows & Embedded and the Regular Windows 7 Versions can be booted from USB 3.0 by integrating USB 3.0 Drivers into the install.wim.

You will have to download the USB 3.0 drivers from your Vendor's website.
Integrate these drivers into your Install.wim using DISM. Then apply/install Windows & to your USB 3.0 Drive

For more details read the below links.

http://www.rmprepusb.com/tutorials/win7onusb#TOC-Add-USB-3.0-Drivers-to-an-Offline-Image-by-Using-DISM

http://reboot.pro/topic/19396-nt-6x-fast-installer-only-boots-wusb-20-wont-boot-usb-30/

http://reboot.pro/topic/10126-nt-6x-fast-installer-install-win7-directly-to-usb-external-drive/page-9#entry123208

http://reboot.pro/topic/10126-nt-6x-fast-installer-install-win7-directly-to-usb-external-drive/page-9#entry123208

To install Windows 7 to a USB Drive i.e, to Enable Windows To Go on regular versions of Windows 7 you can use WinNTSetup or NT Fast Installer.

http://agnipulse.com/2012/11/windows-to-go-all-versions-windows-7-8/