# Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool Fails For Embedded 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, installation, windows-embedded-7

Windows embedded compact 7 ISO, Size 7.76 GB with 16GB USB storage.

Steps Tried:

- [Formatted USB drive as described here.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/unable-to-copy-files-using-windows-7-usbdvd/bd21e76d-5174-4f76-8db5-36df105a12c5)
- [Followed the same procedure of installing "regular" Windows 7 from a
  USB.](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/a/install-windows-7-usb.htm)
- [Install Windows Embedded Standard 7 from USB](https://superuser.com/questions/313450/install-windows-embedded-standard-7-from-usb)

**Results (fails):**

[image]

**However, it did copy over these files. Are they are valid?**

[image]

Will this tool work for Embedded 7?

Thank You.

Comment: try Rufus instead: http://rufus.akeo.ie/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method will **NOT** work for Windows Embedded ***Compact*** 7.

WEC7 download is not an installer.

It is intended for the developer to create the OS image via VS2008.

For instructions, please see:
http://www.embedded101.com/Blogs/SamuelPhung/tabid/72/entryid/201/Windows-Embedded-Compact-7-Getting-Started-Part-1-Introduction.aspx